# Ionic 3 / SQLite : How to capture data field from screen in YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mm:ss format and store it in same format in SQLite TEXT column

Tags: sqlite, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have following pages in my LibraryApp, developing using Ionic 3 framework:

- CategoryPage : To add new record in Category table
- BookPage : To add new record in Book table
- Transaction: To add daily transaction where TrxType is either "BookIssued" or "BookReturned"
- CategorySummaryPage: summary for each CategoryID as on specific day
- StudentSummaryPage: summary for each StudentID as on specific day

and following tables in my SQLite database :

- Category(ID INTEGER,Name TEXT)
- Book(ID INTEGER,CategoryID INTEGER,Title TEXT)
- Transaction(TrxID INTEGER, TrxDate TEXT,TrxType TEXT,BookID INTEGER,DueReturnDate TEXT)
- Student(StudentID INTEGER,StudentName TEXT)
- CategorySummary(SummaryDate TEXT,CategoryID INTEGER,TotalBooksIssued INTEGER,TotalBooksReturned INTEGER)
- StudentSummary(SummaryDate TEXT,StudentID INTEGER,TotalBooksIssued INTEGER,TotalBooksReturned INTEGER)

While saving new Transaction record, I am getting TrxDate from User(by default,its today date) and then adding 15days in it to get DueReturnDate

i.e. DueReturnDate=TrxDate+15days.

TypeScript variables to store TrxDate and DueReturnDate are of type "Date"

How to ensure that values stored in above TypeScript variables and database columns are in format "YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm:ss" 
so that when I select data from Transaction table I can do comparison and/or sorting on TrxDate and DueReturnDate

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store the date as YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm:ss format to do this try the below code which will convert the date to YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm:ss format.

```
this.save_details.date = new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: Thanks you. Date().toISOString() is returning time in UTC/GMT and not in local timezone. Is there anyway to preserve timezone as well?